# SSRS Report not Working with parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, static, report, reporting

I am working on an SSRS report. the report has 6 parameters. this is query based report, means data is being fetched through Query. I am facing an issue that when i run the report is do not fetch the data and report show blank.

I have have update query with static parameters and in this case report works just fine and show proper data. but when the query takes parameters then it shows the blank report. means no data is being fetched from the SQL tables.

What might be the problem and what is the solution of this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post query, parameter definition and connection type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its because type of parameter and data entered are not suitably matched.

Comment: it was due to a date parameter that was causing issues